# Problema al leer en el navegador con PHP

Tags: php, url, server

https://github.com/SirJuanR99/bienesRaicesMVC
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me lee las funciones, el echo me lo lee entero en vez de poner solo Domingo, para que funcione el PHP server tengo que actualizar con live server antes, no se como solucionarlo para que funcione normal tampoco escribiendo la ruta o actualizando va normal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si buscas ayuda debes colocar el codigo en modo texto para que otros puedan reproducir tu codigo, la imagenes son solo para ayuda visual....

Comment: vale, voy a incluirlo. Pero independientemente  de eso en todos los archivos php me pasa. Con el Live Server no hay ningún problema

Comment: No sé exactamente a qué te refieres... pero los navegadores NO interpretan PHP, no puedes simplemente acceder a una ruta de un archivo PHP y pretender que tu navegador lo lea correctamente. Por eso se dice que php es un lenguaje de servidor, porque necesitas tener un servidor que ejecute tu archivo PHP y sirva el HTML generado al navegador. Necesitas un servidor para poder "ver" tu php correctamente, no hay otra manera de hacerlo.

Comment: estoy utilizando apache con xampp, antes no me pesaba ese problema y se actualizaba lo que iba escribiendo pero formateaba el ordenador y no funcionaba, actualizo poniendo la ruta con apache puesto y tampoco actualiza bien

Comment: @JuanR puedes agregar tu código en texto con formato código? es dificil leer las imagenes asi como asi. Y de todos modos, VC te está gritando errores en el código.